# Is vectorization of Components defined on scalars possible in OpenMDAO?

Tags: python, functional-programming, openmdao

In the context of functional programming, a function that takes and returns a scalar can be mapped onto lists/vectors to return a list/vector of the mapped values. In regular Python, I would do this either functionally or in NumPy's vectorized fashion:

```
import numpy as np # NumPy import

xs = [1,2,3,4,5] # List of inputs
f = lambda x: x**2 # Some function, which could be the equivalent of an ExplicitComponent

list(map(f, xs)) # Functional style
[ f(x) for x in xs ] # List comprehension
f(np.array(xs)) # NumPy vectorized style
```

Is this type of behaviour attainable using `Component`s? By this I mean a `Component` could take scalar inputs and perform like a normal function, but automatically performs the operations on vectors and lists of varying length as well.

I haven't been able to find anything similar in the documentation. I understand that most of the behaviour in OpenMDAO uses NumPy's vectorization for efficiency, but does this mean all components that could have vector inputs must be written using some kind of `self.options.declare('num_nodes', default=1)` method and passing a global state `n` for the number of nodes for lists/vectors of length/dimension `n` across all `Component`s?

Regarding design considerations, I understand that vectorizations over Cartesian products of input vectors are not implemented by default in NumPy, and that they're more `zip`-like. But it does work like a partially-applied mapped function by default for a single NumPy array, e.g.:

```
>>> xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> f = lambda x,y: x**2 + y**2
>>> f(np.array(xs), np.array([2,4,6,8]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (4,) 
>>> f(np.array(xs), np.array([2,4,6,8,10]))
array([  5,  20,  45,  80, 125])
>>> f(np.array(xs), 1)
array([ 2,  5, 10, 17, 26])
```

An alternative is to use NumPy's `meshgrid()` as follows:

```
xs, ys = [1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8]
f = lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2
xys = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
f(xys[0], xys[1])
```

So would something like this be more feasible (and desirable!) behaviour for `Component`s?

Comment: You've really asked two questions here: 
1) How do you set up a component to have a flexible input array sizing in OpenMDAO? 
2) Once you have that input array, whats the best way to handle the vectorization

The first question is OpenMDAO specific. The second is more general and really deals only with numpy vectorization.

Comment: Perhaps, but I was thinking of possible implementations with two `add_input()` methods, and the question arose: "Under what context the user should provide lists for multiple inputs? Should the `Component` work with something like lists of tuples, i.e. `zip`s, or Cartesian products with the `meshgrid()` built in to the `Component`'s methods?" Depending on the requirement, an option could be provided for each, but I asked mainly to see what considerations that you and the other developers had for this type of design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V3.1 the only way to do this in OpenMDAO is via an option/argument such as `num_nodes` or `vec_size`.

Other users have expressed an interest in allowing dynamically sized IO in components.  For instance, basing he size of an input on the output to which it is connected.  See https://github.com/OpenMDAO/POEMs/pull/51.

We're working on it, but we don't have a time table for when we'll find an acceptable solution at this time.